# Why my bash script prints the same text line twice

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Font colors
STR_RESET="\e[0m"
STR_BLUE="\e[1m\e[34m"
...
echo -e "${STR_BLUE}Building openssl for linux-x86 $VERSION_FILE${STR_RESET}"
...
```

Outputs

```
+ echo -e '\e[1m\e[34mBuilding openssl for linux-x86\e[0m'
Building openssl for linux-x86
```

The second line shows the correct bold font with blue color. But how can I remove the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are executing your script with debug options. See the [Debugging Bash scripts](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) documentation. But I don't know how you started it.

Try putting `set +x` at the beginning of your script to disable debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothesis: there is `set -x` in the script just before `echo`.

> `-x`
> Print a trace of simple commands […] after they are expanded and before they are executed.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin))</sup>

Solution: remove `set -x`.